# Implementing Rust traits cause struct to not be found

Tags: struct, rust, traits

When I implement a trait on a struct in Rust it's causing the struct type not to be found. First, the working code:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  fn new() -> Box<SomeTrait>;
  fn get_some_value(&self) -> int;
}

struct SomeStruct {
  value: int
}

impl SomeStruct {
  fn new() -> Box<SomeStruct> {
    return box SomeStruct { value: 3 };
  }

  fn get_some_value(&self) -> int {
    return self.value;
  }
}

fn main() {
  let obj = SomeStruct::new();
  println!("{}", obj.get_some_value());
}
```

Here the SomeTrait trait isn't being used. Everything works. If I now change the impl of SomeStruct to implement SomeTrait:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  fn new() -> Box<SomeTrait>;
  fn get_some_value(&self) -> int;
}

struct SomeStruct {
  value: int
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
  fn new() -> Box<SomeTrait> {
    return box SomeStruct { value: 3 };
  }

  fn get_some_value(&self) -> int {
    return self.value;
  }
}

fn main() {
  let obj = SomeStruct::new();
  println!("{}", obj.get_some_value());
}
```

I get the error:

```
trait.rs:21:13: 21:28 error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared module `SomeStruct`
trait.rs:21   let obj = SomeStruct::new();
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
trait.rs:21:13: 21:28 error: unresolved name `SomeStruct::new`.
trait.rs:21   let obj = SomeStruct::new();
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is SomeStruct suddenly missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, associated functions (non-method functions) in traits are called via the trait, i.e.  `SomeTrait::new()`. However, if you just write this, the compiler cannot work out *which* impl you're using, as there's no way to specify the `SomeStruct` information (it only works if the special `Self` type is mentioned in the signature somewhere). That is, the compiler needs to be able to work out which version of `new` should be called. (And this is required; they could have very different behaviour:

```
struct Foo;
impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn new() -> Box<SomeTrait> { box Foo as Box<SomeTrait> }
}

struct Bar;
impl SomeTrait for Bar {
    fn new() -> Box<SomeTrait> { 
        println!("hello")
        box Bar as Box<SomeTrait>
    }
}
```

Or something more dramatic than just printing.)

This is a language hole that will be filled by [UFCS](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/16293). For the moment, you need to use the dummy-`Self` trick:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn new(_dummy: Option<Self>) -> Box<SomeTrait>;
    ...
}
```

which is then called like `SomeTrait::new(None::<SomeStruct>)`.

However, I question why you are returning a boxed object from a constructor. This is rarely a good idea, it's normally better to just return the plain type directly, and the user can box it if necessary, that is,

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn new() -> Self;
    ...
}
```

(NB. this signature mentions `Self` and thus the `Option` trick above isn't required.)

---

Sidenote: the error message is rather bad, but it just reflects how these methods are implemented; an associated function in an `impl Foo` is very similar to writing `mod Foo { fn ... }`. You can see it differ by forcing the compiler to create that module:

```
struct Foo;
impl Foo {
    fn bar() {}
}

fn main() {
    Foo::baz();
}
```

prints just

```
<anon>:7:5: 7:13 error: unresolved name `Foo::baz`.
<anon>:7     Foo::baz();
             ^~~~~~~~
```

i.e. the `Foo` "module" exists.